# Trying to get Jenkins build time on the Github repo. Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Tags: jenkins, github

I am trying to achieve a comment of Jenkins build duration to be posted on the Github Pull request. So Jenkins creates a build job for every PR that is created in the Github repository. After every build is taken place, for the performance profiling, I am trying to post build duration on the PR. Is there a way to achieve that in an easier way?

Comment: Easier than what?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/apps/using-content-attachments/ maybe?